# dataSource won't update in cellForItemAt function

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm having problem getting updated dataSource from my `cellForItemAt`.

```
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! QuestLogCollectionViewCell
    cell.delegate = self
    let task = board[indexPath.section].tasks[indexPath.row]
    cell.task = task
    cell.taskLabel.text = task.action
    cell.ifTaskCompleted = task.ifTaskComplete
    return cell
}
```

when user tapped the checkBox button, `buttonTapped` function will be called and pass data via protocol.

```
    func buttonTapped() {
    guard let taskStatus = ifTaskCompleted else {return}
    if taskStatus == true {
        checkBoxButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "box"), for: .normal)
    } else {
        checkBoxButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "checkedBox"), for: .normal)
    }
    delegate?.userMarkedTaskCompleted(ifTaskComplete: !taskStatus, for: self)
}

    func userMarkedTaskCompleted(ifTaskComplete: Bool, for cell: QuestLogCollectionViewCell) {
    guard let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPath(for: cell) else {return}
    var tasks = board[indexPath.section].tasks
    tasks[indexPath.row].ifTaskComplete = ifTaskComplete
    collectionView?.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I'm having problem getting updated dataSource from my cellForItemAt?" What is happening? Have you added breakpoints and/or log statements to figure out what's happening? What debugging have you done?

Comment: yes i did use log statements and were able to identify that ifTaskComplete inside cellForItemAt function did not reflect on the updated ifTaskComplete. I used log statement to print the ifTaskComplete in both userMarkedTaskCompleted and cellForItemAt. They don't match

Comment: Is your task a value type (`struct`) or reference type (`class`)?

Answer (score 1):

The line `var tasks = board[indexPath.section].tasks` could be problematic. Specifically, if your task types are value types (e.g. `struct` types), then you could be updating a copy of the original structure.

I'd suggest you update the `board`/`tasks` structure directly:

```
func userMarkedTaskCompleted(ifTaskComplete: Bool, for cell: QuestLogCollectionViewCell) {
    guard let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPath(for: cell) else {return}
    board[indexPath.section].tasks[indexPath.row].ifTaskComplete = ifTaskComplete
    collectionView?.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
}
```